# Compiling to ASM on an ARM chip, why are only r1, r2 and r3 registers used

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I am just starting out looking into ARM assembly on a Raspberry Pi (any links to good docs would be appreciated in the comments)

I have a C++ program that I compiled to Assembler using the following command

```
 g++ -S -fverbose-asm -march=armv6j -mtune=arm1176jzf-s file.cpp
```

I can then inspect file.s which is great and it makes some kind of sense. However I thought that the ARM chips had 15 general purpose registers my reading of this code is that it is only using r1 - r3

```
mov     r3, r3, asl #1  @ tmp166, tmp166,
add     r3, r3, r2      @ tmp166, tmp166, D.24883
mov     r2, r3, asl #3  @ tmp167, tmp166,
add     r3, r3, r2      @ tmp166, tmp166, tmp167
rsb     r2, r3, r1      @ D.24883, tmp166, tmp161
```

I can't see an occurrence of a register higher than r3 in the generated code. Is there something I am fundamentally understanding? Is there a good reason for this? Or is the generated code suboptimal?

**UPDATE**

1. if I compile with `-O2` it does use more registers, so I'm assuming that it is something GCC chooses to do. Not sure quite why or which switch controls this behavior.
2. I have also read that r1 -r4 can be used without resetting their state, so I guess for small functions this is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The ARM ABI, which is not uncommon to other processor families, is that when the compiler generates code for the target, some registers are used for passing in parameters, one/some registers are used for returning a result, and some registers dont have to be preserved, basically you can muck with them without worry, and the rest of the registers you need to preserve (push/pop to/from stack) if you need to use them.

arm uses r0-r3 to pass in parameters, and r0 to return a result.  r0-r3 are also considered disposable (and perhaps one more high register) so if the program is simple enough and doesnt need too many registers it will try to use r0-r3 for performance (not needing to use the stack).

Crafting high level code to drive the machine code is an art form you need to understand the compilers and processor, etc.  You are on the right path but need to write many many more functions compile and examine the machine code generated.

Answer (score 1):

Register usage is defined by two constraints then again how effectively they are used is up to the compiler.

- ABI
- ARM/Thumb execution state

ABI is a convention, it is as its name suggest about providing binary compatibility. [ARM ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html), one part of ABI defines which registers are used for function calls. `ARM ABI` states r0-r3 are used for function calls. An ARM compiler supporting ARM ABI needs to behave this way, meaning this as a constraint on register usage.

Another constraint is ARM/Thumb execution modes. Some ARM CPUs can run in Thumb execution mode where most instructions can only access the first eight of the ARM core registers, r0-r7 (ARM ARM 4.1). This also puts a constraint on compiler on how many registers it can use.

Rest is up to the quality of compiler, optimization mode and debugging support.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code is not complex enough to require more registers.

Comment: Could you be more specific, or is this just a guess.

Comment: You didn't even provide the 'C++' code, so of course it is a *guess*.